# React Native Timeline listview is not rendering

Tags: listview, react-native, timeline

I have used the `Basic Usage` timeline list view in my ract-native page (library `ract-native-timeline-listview`). It worked for its default data.
But when I include data via `componentWillMount()`

```
componentWillMount() {
    var list = CustomerStore.usagelist;
    this.setState({data:list});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
}
```

the log is printing the data before runnning the render() but the listview is not showing instead it throws a warning

> Warning: In next release empty section headers will be rendered. In this release you can use 'enableEmptySections' flag to render empty section headers.

I have also used the flag, but there is no use.

```
<Timeline data={this.state.data} enableEmptySections={true} />
```

Does anybody have a solution for this?

I am using React-Native :0.38

[Link to the library](https://github.com/thegamenicorus/react-native-timeline-listview)

Comment: include render functions (i.e renderEvent, renderDetail, renderCircle, renderTime etc)

Comment: thank you..                                                                                                       I have resolved it by Pull Refresh type of list view in react-native-timeline-listview.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still searching for this one, 
it became npm i react-native-timeline-flatlist

just give flex:1 to the contained View or height:"100%"

```
<View style={{height:"100%"}}> 
  //TimelineListView is a separate component i made
   <TimelineListView>
 </View>
```